# Inconsistent Browser Reaction to Script URLs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a Nivo slide gallery and am experiencing some weird inconsistency between browsers.

In order for slider images to appear in Firefox and Chrome, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

To get them to render in IE9, I have to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

I'm using master pages. When the content page is at the root, this problem doesn't occur; it only occurs when the content page is in a folder.

Can anyone shed some light on this and suggest a workaround? Register the script in the code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be sure you have the correct assets either work with absolute paths

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/scripts/my_script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/my_script.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first option works, although I would like a single way to write it so that it works on both localhost and prod' server? Second option only works in IE...

Comment: when communicating with the server it seems that the browser send different things... have you mabe checked the access log of your webserver which calls are incoming?